# C++ pointer "error: double free or corruption (out)"

Tags: c++, pointers

This is my code:

```
uint16_t * ptemparr = new uint16_t[20];
for (int x=0;x<2;x++)
{
   function(ptemparr);
   ptemparr ++;

}
delete[] ptemparr;
```

When I do that I get this error:

```
double free or corruption (out)
```

EDITED:
Thank you I understood why I get this error, now do you think this is a better idea?

```
uint16_t temparr[20];
uint16_t * ptemparr = temparr;
for (int x=0;x<2;x++)
{
   function(ptemparr);
   ptemparr ++;

}
```

This way I make the pointer on the stack and there's no memory leak issue.
Also, this code above has to run every 1 sec, so please bare this in mind before letting me know what's the best coding practice for this situation

Comment: why don't you use brackets for indexing?

Comment: funtion returns an array inside ptemparr, the above code is just for illustration purposes, and the ++ is in reality a ptemparr= ptemparr+ 4

Comment: @Kam, If you always allocate x (x=20 in your code snippet), then you'd better use static allocation, even if once a second is "rather seldom" and the difference between static and dynamic allocation would tend to disappear in the time. Then, using the stack or the heap is a matter of taste: if that vector needs to be accessed outside the block, the heap is mandatory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass the same address to `delete []` which was returned by `new []`.
Also, make sure `function()` does not`deallocate the memory by calling`delete`on the passed pointer.

Comment: @Kam: Yes, the second approach is better.It is always a good idea to avoid dynamic allocations in C++.In fact best of C++ codes will have least use of `new`.And if at all, never with raw pointers.

Answer (score 2):

you need to reset ptemparr to its home address since you incremented it in your for loop. so, I suggest decrementing it by 2 before deleting it.

`ptemparr-=2;`

Comment: No , and it would work, but it is hardly maintainable, and just asking for future bugs.

Comment: Make a copy of the original for anything that is going to modify the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `delete` the same address returned by `new`.

I always make my loops line this work on a copy of the original pointer, and never modify the original pointer returned by `malloc`or `new`.